# Get source and destination of https packet using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

If I was to get http packets src and dst I would do (packets is the captured packets using scapy.sniff(count=500)) )

```
for i in range(len(packets)):
        packet = packets[i]
        if packet.haslayer(HTTPRequest):
            url = packet[HTTPRequest].Host.decode() + packet[HTTPRequest].Path.decode()
            print(packet[scapy.IP].dst)
            ip = packet[scapy.IP].src
            print(" ")
            print(str(ip) + " wants to go to " + str(url) + " which has a IP of " + str(packet[scapy.IP].dst))
```

How would I do this for HTTPS? I know the https packets contents are encrypted, however the fact that it must go from website to client means there must be a public src and dst. So how would I do that using the above script as a baseline?

Comment: Source and destination are in the IP header, not HTTP.

Comment: @Barmar With that Im just filtering out all the other packet types. Then if a packet has a HTTP layer then I do what you said

Comment: Once you determine that it's an HTTP packet, you need to go back to the IP layer to get the source and destination addresses. There are no addresses in the HTTP layer.

Comment: If you use an application like Wireshark to view a packet capture you'll see how this layering works.